# Should I use HTML 5 for video/audio?

Tags: html, uploading

I would like to use HTML 5 for video/audio viewing, but I have some concerns.  First: HTML 5 is only supported in IE 9+.  Second: What do I do for all the different extensions that are supported/not supported like mp4, wav, and webm?

Comment: Are you talking about *viewing* the media? No browser cares what encoding an uploaded file has.

Comment: Viewing the media, I saw that there are three possible extensions for video and audio that are supported by different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different extensions are supported in different browsers. The solution is...if MP4 is supported by IE, then you will also need to have a WebM or Ogg version of the same video file to ensure cross-browser support of the video (Firefox, Chrome).

Here's a great HTML5-based video/audio player. If a user uses an older browser, the player "falls back" to Flash-based player.
http://videojs.com/

You may find this helpful for converting to various HTML5-supported video formats... http://easyhtml5video.com/

For cloud-based encoding (paid service):
http://zencoder.com/

Comment: The easyhtml5video website cannot be automated, I need something that automates it, that I don't have to drag-and-drop, etc.

Comment: I am not sure whether you are looking for Cloud encoding. If yes, here's something you can use (but may be expensive). http://zencoder.com/

Answer (score -1):

I don't see what HTML5 has to do with uploading of audio / video. HTML is a spec. How do you want to upload stuff (it doesn't matter what is being uploaded) specifically?

HTML5 is supported by user agent x, is mostly not true. You might say user agent x support those features of HTML5 (which still isn't finished btw).

If anything: IE9 doesn't support all features of the HTML5 draft. IE10 is more getting close (close is a relative thing here when talking about IE).

> What do I do for all the different extensions that are supported/not supported like mp4, wav, and webm?

It sounds like you are looking for players rather than uploaders. If that is the case and you want to support as many clients as possible (depending on requirements) you would have to resort to re-encoding of files uploaded. You can re-encode it in different formats and you could handle the support of different user agent (or lack of) HTML5 elements by implementing a fallback to flash.

For audio I have used [Sound Manager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) in some projects which does just that (i.e. use native html5 audio + fallback to flash).